# Launch local apps from a remote desktop session?

Tags: remote-desktop, terminal-server

We have users connect to a Windows Server 2003 terminal server using XP's stock Remote Desktop client. Web browsing is disabled on the terminal server; users are instructed to use their local web browser. When they receive links in email messages (in Outlook in their remote sessions) they chafe at having to copy the url to their local browser instead of just clicking.

Is there a way for the remote desktop client to launch a local app? So clicking a link in the terminal services session would launch IE on the local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve a better integration between applications running on a terminal server and those running on the local system usign Windows 2008 Terminal Services (RemoteApp); but a remote session is completely isolated with Windows Server 2003, apart from clipboard sharing.

Answer (score 3):

No. I hate to be blunt, but there's no connection between apps running in the remote session and apps on the local machine. Citrix might be able to do it, but not TS in W2K3.

Answer (score 0):

Citrix will do this by calling for local resources (Word,Excel, IE, etc, ) first when links are clicked, if the resource didn't exist on the machine for some reason then it would launch on the server (if the resource was available) , but not with Windows TS.